# Using Response.TransmitFile to download file but also contains the page source

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Below is the offending code, I download a csv however it appends the page source to the bottom any ideas on how to prevent this?

```
            var priceList = Test();
            const string downloadName = "PriceList.csv";
            var fs = new FileStream(downloadName, FileMode.Create);

            var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvHelper(fs);
            csv.Writer.WriteRecords(priceList);
            Response.ClearContent();

            //not sure what the correct content type is. This is probally wrong
            Response.ContentType = "application/xls";
            //Setting size is optional               
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
               "attachment; filename=" + downloadName + "; size=" + fs.Length.ToString());
            var fn = fs.Name;
            fs.Close();
            loadingImage.Visible = false;
            Response.TransmitFile(fn);
            Response.Flush();
```

Comment: what happens if you add "Response.End()" after "Response.Flush()"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `Response.End()`.

Also, why save the file just to resend it? At best this is wasteful, but also if you're reusing the name then you've a race-condition if two people hit this page at the same time. Instead of sending the file, use `var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvHelper(Response.OutputStream)` so you write straight to the browser (you'll have to send your headers first though).

Also, the content-type for CSV files is `text/csv`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `Response.End()` method after you flush the stream or try force-download.

Answer (score 0):

```
var priceList = Test();
        const string downloadName = "PriceList.csv";
        var fs = new FileStream(downloadName, FileMode.Create);

        var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvHelper(fs);
        csv.Writer.WriteRecords(priceList);
        Response.ClearContent();

        //not sure what the correct content type is. This is probally wrong
        Response.ContentType = "application/xls";
        //Setting size is optional               
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
           "attachment; filename=" + downloadName + "; size=" + fs.Length.ToString());
        var fn = fs.Name;
        fs.Close();
        loadingImage.Visible = false;
        Response.TransmitFile(fn);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```