# Correct usage of Asp.Net Response.TransmitFile and Response.End()

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the correct usage of this code?

```
httpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(fileName));
httpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
httpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", new FileInfo(physicalFileName).Length.ToString());
httpContext.Response.TransmitFile(physicalFileName);
httpContext.Response.Flush();
httpContext.Response.End();  //Use it or not?
```

Is it really good to use `.Flush()` and `.End()`?

According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/05/25/response-end-response-close-and-how-customer-feedback-helps-us-improve-msdn-documentation.aspx) you should never ever use `Response.End()` (only in error or hacking scenarios)

But in some of the answers the `.End()` is reconmended...?

Like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570269/using-response-transmitfile-to-download-file-but-also-contains-the-page-source) article.

So it is appropriate to use `Response.End` or not?

Answer (score 5):

According to [Thomas Marquardt](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2009/06/25/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect.aspx), you should never use `Response.End()`. Instead you should use `Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`. Check this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/en-us) as well, it's from Microsoft KB, recommending the use of `Application.CompleteRequest()` instead `Response.End()`.

Comment: I think @DanielCuadra raises a valid point that people can still edit the Response if you don't use Response.End.  However I believe Response.SuppressContent would prevent that.

Comment: My answer is attempting to precisely warn that Thomas Marquardt's article did not cover all scenarios and neither listed assumptions/preconditions/caveats to prevent issues on  corner cases scenarios; no person in the world can write error-free articles. Streaming files (as opposed of simply rendering aspx pages) is a operation where writing an unexpected extra byte on the output stream might dramatically affect your site, and it will take you days or weeks to debug and find what the issue was.

Answer (score 5):

I'm adding this so people don't fall into the mistaken accepted response: **Response.End() might be required on most case scenarios after transmitting a file.**

It doesn't matter if you use TransmitFile, or if you decided to write directly into the output stream, simply most of the times you want to ensure no one can write a single byte after you have sent a file.

This is specially important as there will be at some point a filter installed on IIS, a code on global asax EndRequest, or a developer that called your code and then did more things, and any of those will eventually append more stuff into the output stream without you noticing it, and it will corrupt your transmitted file contents.
  - CompleteRequest won't save you from this, as it allows adding more stuff in the response after you call it.

Response.End() is the only way to guarantee no other future code change or IIS filter will manipulate your response as intended.

Comment: In my experience Response.End() causes ThreadAbort exception which is very annoying. It doesn't break anything, but it fills our log with bogus error messages.

Comment: That's absolutely right, and it's very inefficient as well, but I have not found any other way to force that no other code piece will alter the response output stream.Just to put an example, your IT security department might install any day of the year, without asking you, an http module on IIS that will filter the requests and might append a "Copyright" message on the output stream (or inject some enterprise cookies for tracking purposes, etc) just before the response goes through the wire. Imagine having all kind of issues on your downloads without knowing what hit you.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
"The CompleteRequest method does not raise an exception, and code after the call to the CompleteRequest method might be executed. If your intention is to avoid execution of subsequent code, and if the performance penalty of End is acceptable, you can call End instead of CompleteRequest." - Thank you for bringing it up. I completely missed this part.

Comment: Maybe you didn't missed: That part in the documentation was added by MS after multiple people complained of all kind of strange issues for avoiding calling Response.End(). MS ended up admitting there were certainly legit cases and fixed their documentation.

Comment: Doesn't Response.SuppressContent prevent writing to the Response?

Comment: Yes, it prevents it, but you have then to consider several other potential issues: SupressContents will also not flush to the client any errors, meaning your client might hung if something fails on the server (https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=MQXy8HSgxzYC&pg=PT386&lpg=PT386&dq=issue+with+response.suppresscontent&source=bl&ots=i-xDfB32Ts&sig=f5B5cbaIe7IWcWa6ntkvjBoUKkc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip1YK5m_jNAhXm8YMKHUBzAug4ChDoAQgZMAA#v=onepage&q=issue%20with%20response.suppresscontent&f=false). And Response.Close() sends the reset connection network package asynchronously, which has other issues

Comment: An example of issue with the Response.Close() is when the reset network packages arrives EARLIER than the last stream sent by the Response (for example, if you additionally flushed some bytes asynchronously before, either consciously or by calling an API you don't know the implementation of). If the reset connection package happens to arrive earlier on my example, then your stream contents would get truncated and would represent incorrectly what you meant to stream. Add up another couple of wasted weeks for your QAs and developers attempting to reproduce the issue to identify what hit you.